# Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./Merge_gcov_generalised.pl line 226, <FILE2> line 284046 (#1)

Tags: perl

I have written a perl script to merge the gcov files from different machines.
Below is the subroutine i have written for merging.

```
sub merge_gcov()
    {
        open(FILE1, "<$_[0]") or die "can not open file";
        open(FILE2, "<$_[1]") or die "can not open file";
        open(FILE3, ">$_[2]") or die "can not open file";
        my ($line1, $line2 , $flag );
        while ( 1 )
        {  
            $line1 = <FILE1>; # read them each
            $line2 = <FILE2>;
            last unless ( $line1 || $line2 ); # if both empty exit loop
            #
            # otherwise test for which one just finished
            #
            unless( $line1 )
            {
                $flag = 1;
            last;
            }
            unless( $line2 )
            {
                $flag = 2;
            last
            }   
            #
            # now do the voodo on the two lines
            #
            chomp($line2);
            chomp($line1);
            if($line1=~/^\s*-/ and  $line2 =~/^\s*-/)  
            {   
                print FILE3 "$line1\n";
            }
            elsif($line1=~/^\s*#####/ and  $line2 =~/^\s*#####/) 
            {      
                print FILE3 "$line1\n";
            }
            elsif($line1=~/^\s*#####:\s{0,}(\d{1,})/ and  $line2 =~/^\s{0,}(\d{1,})/) 
            {     
                print FILE3 "$line2\n"
            }
            elsif($line1=~/^\s{0,}(\d{1,})/ and  $line2 =~/^\s*#####:\s{0,}(\d{1,})/) 
            {  
                print FILE3 "$line1\n"
            }
            elsif($line1=~/^\s{0,}(\d{1,})/ and  $line2 =~/\s{0,}(\d{1,})/) 
            { 
                my @values1 =  split(/:/, "$line1");
                my @values2 =  split(/:/, "$line2");
                print FILE3 ("      ",$values1[0]+$values2[0]),":","$values1[1]:","$values1[2]\n";
            }
            else
            {  
                print FILE3 "$line1\n";
                print FILE3 "$line2\n";
             }

        }
    close(FILE3);
    }
```

Merging is done properly but after merging i am getting  below error....

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
        ./Merge_gcov_generalised.pl line 226, <FILE2> line 284046 (#1)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
        ./Merge_gcov_generalised.pl line 226, <FILE2> line 284414 (#1)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
        ./Merge_gcov_generalised.pl line 226, <FILE2> line 302995 (#1)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
        ./Merge_gcov_generalised.pl line 226, <FILE2> line 311633 (#1)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
        ./Merge_gcov_generalised.pl line 226, <FILE2> line 311962 (#1)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
        ./Merge_gcov_generalised.pl line 226, <FILE2> line 321536 (#1)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
        ./Merge_gcov_generalised.pl line 226, <FILE2> line 323445 (#1)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
        ./Merge_gcov_generalised.pl line 226, <FILE2> line 329553 (#1)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
        ./Merge_gcov_generalised.pl line 226, <FILE2> line 336009 (#1)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
        ./Merge_gcov_generalised.pl line 226, <FILE2> line 336330 (#1)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
        ./Merge_gcov_generalised.pl line 226, <FILE2> line 338188 (#1)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
        ./Merge_gcov_generalised.pl line 226, <FILE2> line 343170 (#1)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
        ./Merge_gcov_generalised.pl line 226, <FILE2> line 349037 (#1)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
        ./Merge_gcov_generalised.pl line 226, <FILE2> line 349610 (#1)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
        ./Merge_gcov_generalised.pl line 226, <FILE2> line 633937 (#1)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
        ./Merge_gcov_generalised.pl line 226, <FILE2> line 634509 (#1)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
        ./Merge_gcov_generalised.pl line 226, <FILE2> line 634877 (#1)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
        ./Merge_gcov_generalised.pl line 226, <FILE2> line 653458 (#1)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
        ./Merge_gcov_generalised.pl line 226, <FILE2> line 662096 (#1)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
        ./Merge_gcov_generalised.pl line 226, <FILE2> line 662425 (#1)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
        ./Merge_gcov_generalised.pl line 226, <FILE2> line 671999 (#1)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
```

I know i don't get these warnings when i used **no warnings**,But is there any other way to remove these warnings.

Line 226 is :**print FILE3 ("  ",$values1[0]+$values2[0]),":","$values1[1]:","$values1[2]\n";**

Comment: Your code is painful to look at. There are 5 things wrong in the first three lines alone. :-(

Comment: `{0,}` aka `*`, and `{1,}` aka `+`. What's with the obfuscation?

Comment: These warnings mean that either `$values1[1]` or `$values1[2]` is undefined. Which means that your split yields too few elements to fill the array that far. So it is a sign that your data is corrupt, or that you have edge cases which breaks your parser. Check the input for those lines and see how to handle these edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is get rid of *that* particular warning that you already expect and *have accounted for*, then all you have to do is this:

```
{    no warnings 'uninitialized';
     # **Small** bit of code causing the problem.
     say "A string and $probably_undefined";
}
```

The reason I stress, *small* code is that Perl does not have a thousand warning categories to turn on and off by pragma. It has several rather broad categories that if you leave disarmed for too large a space *will* bite you. The idea is to look at *each* warned condition and decide if an uninitialized value has no effect--or one that you can at least account for.

Answer (score 0):

You test for one or the other of the lines being uninitialized but you never use that information, so you're printing an `undef` concatenated with a newline in your final `else`; this is the source of your warnings.

Your `gcov` files actually have a bunch of excess newlines in them, caused by one file running out first, one per each unmatched line. They're only valid because `gcov` is either very forgiving in what it accepts, or because `gcov` stops reading the input silently when it sees the first bare newline. The first is great; the second is very bad.

To fix this, we need to figure out where we expect to have an `undef` and what to do when we find one. This code can generate `undef` in `$line1` and `$line2` when we hit the end of each file. Let's look at how you use these to see where `undef` is OK and where it's not.

1. Testing for both lines being false (e.g., `undef`): this is a good use of `undef`.
2. Setting `$flag`: good usage, but bad logic, since you never use `$flag` again.
3. Pattern matches: good usage, because pattern matches against nothing should (and do) fail, and this is correct for your code.
4. Printing a line that might be `undef`: bad usage, as this will generate your warning and output an extra empty newline.

Because the pattern matches will all fail against an `undef`, you can just skip the code that sets `$flag` altogether and make the last `else` look like this:

```
...
else {
    # One or the other file has run out already. Note that
    # the $line variables being undef here is OK because that's
    # an expected possible value that we're actually testing for.
    # We could used "defined $lineX" but since undef itself is 
    # false, this is okay.
    print FILE3 "$line1" if $line1;
    print FILE3 "$line2" if $line2;
}
```

Now for some `undef` philosophizing.

An uninitialized variable warning is almost always a logic error somewhere, despite Perl being nice about fixing it up. If you are getting these, you should look for the following:

1. Am I calling something that is returning an `undef`? If so, am I calling it wrong, or with bad parameters? Can I substitute a default value without it being erroneous, like 0 or '' (using the defined-or `//` operator), if my call is valid? Do I need a table or sub to give me default values instead? If I can't use a default value, what's wrong with my logic?
2. If that's not the case, am I referencing an uninitialized array or hash entry? Perl will *auto-vivify* those entries and set them to `undef`. Is my index or key bad? If not, should I be setting those entries to a default value myself, bounds-checking my index for an array, or checking if the hash element `exists` for a hash? Otherwise the criteria in 1. apply.
3. If neither of those is the case, I have an uninitialized scalar variable. Why isn't it initialized? What should I have initialized it to? What assumption did I *forget to make* (by not initializing the scalar to a known value)?

Generally speaking, unless your code is supposed to issue a warning (e.g., you added a `warn` to it), a warning means something isn't as you expected it to be. You should look at that and see why, not just hide the diagnostic.